# Is there a way to prevent "reset role" in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling, pgbouncer

Is there a way to prevent a user from running "reset role" in PostgreSQL, and thus gaining permission he may not have ?

I have an architecture with many databases on a single server. An API connects to several databases on a local PostgreSQL server. I had planned to use Pgbouncer but it sounds like I would have to map one database/user in pgbouncer to the same database/user in PostgreSQL which sounds counter productive. Instead I would like to be able to reuse connections but have different authorization for different user upon connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1**
`RESET ROLE` would just "return" you back to the role you used to login. [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-role.html)
also `SET ROLE rolename`

> must be a role that the current session user is a member of

so " gaining permission he may not have" is not the case.

**2**
pgbouncer indeed will require such mapping.

**3** to "reuse connections but have different authorization for different user upon connection." you can use [set authorization](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-session-authorization.html) which is very similar to `SET ROLE`.

There is no session pooler that would do it for you I believe...

Comment: There are contexts where it is useful for a proxy to be able to re-use connections for different users. This requires a proxy that connects as a powerful user, and temporarily restricts permissions. The "SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION" documentation says "The user name can be written as either an identifier or a string literal. Using this command, it is possible, for example, to temporarily become an unprivileged user and later switch back to being a superuser."

Comment: The problem is ensuring that the proxy can switch back to being a superuser when a new user connects, but that a connected user can't gain superuser permissions for themselves while connected.

Comment: But returning to a previous role could still be problematic! If the connection starts out with an authenticator role that can either switch to a restricted or unrestricted role, and this user was switched to the restricted role, could then reset and issue a set role. It could do so by abusing the application logic (sql injection perhaps).

Answer (score 2):

[PostgreSQL set_user Extension Module](https://github.com/pgaudit/set_user) with a token could be an option.

You could make PgBouncer reset the role back using `server_reset_query`.